# Binary Clasification Accurary

Tags: classification, accuracy, binary

newbie speaking:

Commonly we can say that accuracy is defined as total positive/ total nbr cases.

But I read that, when it is a binary classifier we should consider: TP+TN/ total nbr cases.

Can someone explain to me why?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Accuracy is commonly defined as **total nbr of correct predictions / total nbr of predictions**.
Imagine a binary classification of color in: White or not White.

Since it's binary, all the white Classifications - **a True Positive classification** are as important for accuracy as a - **True Negative classification**, after all, the classification is also correct, hence,
TP+TN/ total nbr of predictions.

Comment: Yes indeed. In case it helps Wikipedia has a quite complete summary about classification evaluation measures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall